# Adding p-values to a polr model (for modelsummary)

Tags: r, ordinal, modelsummary

I know that `polr` does not give p-values because they are not very reliable. Nevertheless, I would like to add them to my `modelsummary` ([Vignette](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-models-part-i-)) output. I know to get the values as follows:

```
library(MASS)
polr_res <- polr(as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, Hess=TRUE, data=fullauto);summary(polr_res)

Call:
polr_res(formula = as.ordered(rep77) ~ foreign + length + mpg, data = fullauto, 
    Hess = TRUE)

## coefficient test
library("AER")
coeftest(polr_res)
```

## modelsummary

Because `polr` has no p-values, I cannot call `modelsummary(models, stars=TRUE)` on my `models` (which includes other models which do have p-values and for which I want to show stars).

```
library(modelsummary)
models <- list(
"Ordinal Probit" = polr_res,
)
# model_names <- c("OLS", "")
modelsummary(models, stars=TRUE)
```

I tried first to simply add the p-values to the `tidy` object, but I cannot add that object to the list of `models`.

```
polr_pval <- coeftest(polr)[,4]
polr_pval <- as.data.frame(polr_pval)
tidy_polr <- tidy(polr)
tidy_polr[,5] <- polr_pval
```

The vignette describes that I can make a custom class which adapts the `polr`, but I do not understand how:
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-i-

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-ii-

Could anyone help me figure this out?

## EDIT:

I am posting an edit showing the problem I was having when using Vincent's answer, with `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)`. If you are encountering this issue, (preferably) update to R version 4.0.0 or download an update for `modelsummary` from Github (see also Vincent's comments below).:

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github('vincentarelbundock/modelsummary')
```

Output:

[image]

## DATA for R

```
fullauto <- structure(list(make = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23), label = "Make", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(AMC = 1, Audi = 2, BMW = 3, 
Buick = 4, Cad. = 5, Chev. = 6, Datsun = 7, Dodge = 8, Fiat = 9, 
Ford = 10, Honda = 11, Linc. = 12, Mazda = 13, Merc. = 14, Olds = 15, 
Peugeot = 16, Plym. = 17, Pont. = 18, Renault = 19, Subaru = 20, 
Toyota = 21, VW = 22, Volvo = 23)), model = structure(c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5000, 320, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 200, 210, 510, 810, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 98, 604, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 260), label = "Model", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Concord = 1, Pacer = 2, Spirit = 3, 
Fox = 4, Century = 5, Electra = 6, LeSabre = 7, Opel = 8, Regal = 9, 
Riviera = 10, Skylark = 11, Deville = 12, Eldrado = 13, Seville = 14, 
Chevette = 15, Impala = 16, Malibu = 17, MCarlo = 18, Monza = 19, 
Nova = 20, Colt = 21, Diplomat = 22, Magnum = 23, StRegis = 24, 
Strada = 25, Fiesta = 26, Mustang = 27, Accord = 28, Civic = 29, 
Cntntl = 30, `Mark V` = 31, Vrsills = 32, GLC = 33, Bobcat = 34, 
Cougar = 35, `XR-7` = 36, Marquis = 37, Monarch = 38, Zephyr = 39, 
Cutlass = 40, CutlSupr = 41, `Delta 88` = 42, Omega = 43, Starfire = 44, 
Toronado = 45, Arrow = 46, Champ = 47, Horizon = 48, Sapporo = 49, 
Volare = 50, Catalina = 51, Firebird = 52, GranPrix = 53, `Le Mans` = 54, 
Phoenix = 55, Sunbird = 56, `Le Car` = 57, Subaru = 58, Celica = 59, 
Corolla = 60, Corona = 61, Rabbit = 62, Diesel = 63, Scirocco = 64, 
Dasher = 65)), price = structure(c(4099, 4749, 3799, 6295, 9690, 
9735, 4816, 7827, 5788, 4453, 5189, 10372, 4082, 11385, 14500, 
15906, 3299, 5705, 4504, 5104, 3667, 3955, 6229, 4589, 5079, 
8129, 3984, 4010, 5886, 6342, 4296, 4389, 4187, 5799, 4499, 11497, 
13594, 13466, 3995, 3829, 5379, 6303, 6165, 4516, 3291, 4733, 
5172, 4890, 4181, 4195, 10371, 8814, 12990, 4647, 4425, 4482, 
6486, 4060, 5798, 4934, 5222, 4723, 4424, 4172, 3895, 3798, 5899, 
3748, 5719, 4697, 5397, 6850, 7140, 11995), label = "Price", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    mpg = structure(c(22, 17, 22, 23, 17, 25, 20, 15, 18, 26, 
    20, 16, 19, 14, 14, 21, 29, 16, 22, 22, 24, 19, 23, 35, 24, 
    21, 30, 18, 16, 17, 21, 28, 21, 25, 28, 12, 12, 14, 30, 22, 
    14, 14, 15, 18, 20, 19, 19, 18, 19, 24, 16, 21, 14, 38, 34, 
    25, 26, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 24, 26, 35, 18, 31, 18, 25, 
    41, 25, 23, 17), label = "Mileage (mpg)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    rep78 = structure(c(3, 3, NA, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 
    3, 4, NA, 3, 5, 3, NA, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5), label = "Repair Record 1978", format.stata = "%9.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Poor = 1, Fair = 2, Average = 3, 
    Good = 4, Excellent = 5)), rep77 = structure(c(2, 1, NA, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 2, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), label = "Repair Record 1977", format.stata = "%9.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Poor = 1, Fair = 2, Average = 3, 
    Good = 4, Excellent = 5)), hdroom = structure(c(2.5, 3, 3, 
    2.5, 3, 2.5, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 4, 
    3.5, 2, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 4, 4, 4.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
    2, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 
    2, 4, 4.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 4, 1.5, 5, 4, 1.5, 2, 
    3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.5), label = "Headroom (in.)", format.stata = "%6.1f"), 
    rseat = structure(c(27.5, 25.5, 18.5, 28, 27, 26, 29, 31.5, 
    30.5, 24, 28.5, 30, 27, 31.5, 30, 30, 26, 29.5, 28.5, 28.5, 
    25, 27, 21, 23.5, 22, 27, 24, 29, 29, 28, 26.5, 26, 23, 25.5, 
    23.5, 30.5, 28.5, 27, 25.5, 25.5, 29.5, 25, 30.5, 27, 29, 
    28, 28, 29, 27, 25.5, 30, 31.5, 30.5, 21.5, 23, 25, 22, 31, 
    29, 23.5, 28.5, 28, 27, 25, 23, 25.5, 22, 24.5, 23, 25.5, 
    25.5, 23.5, 37.5, 29.5), label = "Rear Seat (in.)", format.stata = "%6.1f"), 
    trunk = structure(c(11, 11, 12, 11, 15, 12, 16, 20, 21, 10, 
    16, 17, 13, 20, 16, 13, 9, 20, 17, 16, 7, 13, 6, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 17, 17, 21, 16, 9, 10, 10, 5, 22, 18, 15, 11, 9, 16, 16, 
    23, 15, 17, 16, 16, 20, 14, 10, 17, 20, 14, 11, 11, 17, 8, 
    16, 20, 7, 16, 17, 13, 7, 10, 11, 14, 9, 11, 15, 15, 16, 
    12, 14), label = "Trunk space (cu. ft.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    weight = structure(c(2930, 3350, 2640, 2070, 2830, 2650, 
    3250, 4080, 3670, 2230, 3280, 3880, 3400, 4330, 3900, 4290, 
    2110, 3690, 3180, 3220, 2750, 3430, 2370, 2020, 2280, 2750, 
    2120, 3600, 3600, 3740, 2130, 1800, 2650, 2240, 1760, 4840, 
    4720, 3830, 1980, 2580, 4060, 4130, 3720, 3370, 2830, 3300, 
    3310, 3690, 3370, 2730, 4030, 4060, 3420, 3260, 1800, 2200, 
    2520, 3330, 3700, 3470, 3210, 3200, 3420, 2690, 1830, 2050, 
    2410, 2200, 2670, 1930, 2040, 1990, 2160, 3170), label = "Weight (lbs.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    length = structure(c(186, 173, 168, 174, 189, 177, 196, 222, 
    218, 170, 200, 207, 200, 221, 204, 204, 163, 212, 193, 200, 
    179, 197, 170, 165, 170, 184, 163, 206, 206, 220, 161, 147, 
    179, 172, 149, 233, 230, 201, 154, 169, 221, 217, 212, 198, 
    195, 198, 198, 218, 200, 180, 206, 220, 192, 170, 157, 165, 
    182, 201, 214, 198, 201, 199, 203, 179, 142, 164, 174, 165, 
    175, 155, 155, 156, 172, 193), label = "Length (in.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    turn = structure(c(40, 40, 35, 36, 37, 34, 40, 43, 43, 34, 
    42, 43, 42, 44, 43, 45, 34, 43, 31, 41, 40, 43, 35, 32, 34, 
    38, 35, 46, 46, 46, 36, 33, 43, 36, 34, 51, 48, 41, 33, 39, 
    48, 45, 44, 41, 43, 42, 42, 42, 43, 40, 43, 43, 38, 37, 37, 
    36, 38, 44, 42, 42, 45, 40, 43, 41, 34, 36, 36, 35, 36, 35, 
    35, 36, 36, 37), label = "Turn Circle (ft.) ", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    displ = structure(c(121, 258, 121, 97, 131, 121, 196, 350, 
    231, 304, 196, 231, 231, 425, 350, 350, 231, 250, 200, 200, 
    151, 250, 119, 85, 119, 146, 98, 318, 318, 225, 105, 98, 
    140, 107, 91, 400, 400, 302, 86, 140, 302, 302, 302, 250, 
    140, 231, 231, 231, 231, 151, 350, 350, 163, 156, 86, 105, 
    119, 225, 231, 231, 231, 231, 231, 151, 79, 97, 134, 97, 
    134, 89, 90, 97, 97, 163), label = "Displacement (cu. in.)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    gratio = structure(c(3.57999992370605, 2.52999997138977, 
    3.07999992370605, 3.70000004768372, 3.20000004768372, 3.64000010490417, 
    2.9300000667572, 2.41000008583069, 2.73000001907349, 2.86999988555908, 
    2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 2.27999997138977, 
    2.19000005722046, 2.24000000953674, 2.9300000667572, 2.55999994277954, 
    2.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.55999994277954, 
    3.89000010490417, 3.70000004768372, 3.53999996185303, 3.54999995231628, 
    3.53999996185303, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 2.94000005722046, 
    3.36999988555908, 3.15000009536743, 3.07999992370605, 3.04999995231628, 
    3.29999995231628, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 2.47000002861023, 
    3.73000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 2.75, 2.75, 2.25999999046326, 
    2.4300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 
    2.73000001907349, 3.07999992370605, 2.73000001907349, 2.41000008583069, 
    2.41000008583069, 3.57999992370605, 3.04999995231628, 2.97000002861023, 
    3.36999988555908, 3.53999996185303, 3.23000001907349, 2.73000001907349, 
    3.07999992370605, 2.9300000667572, 2.9300000667572, 3.07999992370605, 
    2.73000001907349, 3.72000002861023, 3.80999994277954, 3.05999994277954, 
    3.21000003814697, 3.04999995231628, 3.77999997138977, 3.77999997138977, 
    3.77999997138977, 3.74000000953674, 2.98000001907349), label = "Gear Ratio", format.stata = "%6.2f"), 
    order = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
    28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
    43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 46, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
    58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
    73, 74), label = "Original order", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    foreign = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Foreign", format.stata = "%8.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(Domestic = 0, Foreign = 1
    )), wgtd = structure(c(2930, 3350, 2640, NA, NA, NA, 3250, 
    4080, 3670, 2230, 3280, 3880, 3400, 4330, 3900, 4290, 2110, 
    3690, 3180, 3220, 2750, 3430, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2120, 3600, 
    3600, 3740, NA, 1800, 2650, NA, NA, 4840, 4720, 3830, NA, 
    2580, 4060, 4130, 3720, 3370, 2830, 3300, 3310, 3690, 3370, 
    2730, 4030, 4060, NA, 3260, 1800, 2200, 2520, 3330, 3700, 
    3470, 3210, 3200, 3420, 2690, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), format.stata = "%9.0g"), wgtf = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 2070, 2830, 2650, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2370, 2020, 2280, 2750, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2130, NA, NA, 2240, 1760, NA, NA, NA, 1980, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3420, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1830, 2050, 2410, 
    2200, 2670, 1930, 2040, 1990, 2160, 3170), format.stata = "%9.0g")), label = "Automobile Models", row.names = c(NA, 
-74L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to define a [`tidy_custom.polr` method as described here in the documentation.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-information-to-existing-models-1). For instance, you could do:

```r
library(MASS)
library(AER)
library(modelsummary)

tidy_custom.polr <- function(x, ...) {
  s <- coeftest(x)
  out <- data.frame(
    term = row.names(s),
    p.value = s[, "Pr(>|z|)"])
  out
}

mod = list(
  "LM" = lm(gear ~ hp + mpg, data = mtcars),
  "POLR" = polr(as.ordered(gear) ~ hp + mpg, data = mtcars))

modelsummary(mod, stars = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I looked at these custom function, but I couldn't really figure out what to do exactly. Now that I have seen what you did, it looks very simple haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just tested it with my actual data. Although it runs the model, all the coefficient names are replaced by numbers. Do you perhaps know what might be causing that?

Comment: I checked the data frame within `tidy.custom.polr`, but that dataframe has the correct names.

Comment: What versions of R and modelsummary are you using? Sounds like a factor vs. character situation. Maybe try a tibble instead of the data.frame in the tidy_custom function.

Comment: I tried. Same result regrettably. I am using `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) - modelsummary_0.7.0`

Comment: Updated all packages, re-ran with minimal libraries, but same result. I have the same problem with the example data by the way.

Comment: This is almost certainly related to your R version, which is almost 2 years old (please consider upgrading). Since 4.0.0, `as.data.frame` no longer converts characters to factors automatically. I just pushed an update to the `modelsummary` repo on Github with a hack to make it work on earlier versions, and I included a test with this specific code chunk, which seems to pass on old versions of R. If you try the Github version, make sure you restart a fresh R session with no history at all before running the code again.

Comment: That works! You are a life saver! I was planning to wait with upgrading until after I graduate haha.. I tried running my code on the office computer (with 4.0.0) and everything turned red.. So I am too scared to update my laptop.